# Pass event to another function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jshint

```
var that = this;

for(var i=0;i<x;++i){
// some code
events={
   click: function(event){
     that.doClick(event,this);
}
}
}
```

Now with above code I am getting JShint error:

> "Dont make functions within loop".

To resolve above error I am doing this now:

```
   var that = this;
    function clickHandler() {
                return function() {
                    that.doClick(this);
                };
            }

for(var i=0;i<x;++i){
// some code
events={
   click: clickHandler()
}
}
```

Is this fine? If yes then how can I pass event from click event to `clickHandler` and then to `doClick` function?

Comment: There's no difference in your first chunk of code to your second, except in your second you dont pass `clickHandler` - you execute it and assign the result to `click`.

Comment: How can I pass event to doClick in second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not fine. The problem in creating functions inside a loop is that you create a new copy of the function at each iteration.

In your second code, you call `clickHandler` at each iteration, which will return a different copy of the function each time. So it's still the same problem.

Instead, a better way is creating the function only once before the loop, and reference it inside:

```js
var that = this;
function clickHandler(event) {
   that.doClick(event, this);
}
for(var i=0; i<x; ++i){
  var events = {click: clickHandler};
}
```

However, since `events` does not seem to depend on `i`, you can move it outside too:

```js
var that = this,
    events = {click: function(event){
      that.doClick(event, this);
    }};
for(var i=0; i<x; ++i){
  /* Use `events` here */
}
```

Comment: Now getting another jshint warning on that.doClick(event, this); "Possible strict voilation"

Comment: @Alien01 jshint doesn't know that you will only use that function as a method, so it warns that the value of `this` will be the global object in non-strict mode and undefined in strict mode. You can add `/*jshint validthis: true */` inside `clickHandler` to ignore that warning, or name it `ClickHandler` to make jshint think it's a constructor. Alternatively, use my second code.